# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to read multiple values from parameter, store it in a variable and later use it in the select statement to pull multiple values.

```
declare @codes XML = N'<Root>
                          <List Value="120" />
                          <List Value="110" />
                         </Root>';

declare @codeList VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')  FROM  @codes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item));

WITH CODE_RESULT AS(      
       SELECT  ID, Name, Region,
                 FROM dbo.MyTable1    
                 WHERE
                 (@codes IS NULL OR DataCode IN ( @codeList))

       ...

       UNION

       SELECT  ID, Name, Region,
                 FROM dbo.MyTable2    
                 WHERE
                 (@codes IS NULL OR DataCode IN ( @codeList))

       ...
```

But, I am getting the following exception:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

**Expectation:**

How do I store the parameter values in a variable and later reuse it in multiple select statements under 'in' clause? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Declare it as a table variable and use `select .. into`. Then you can use it in a query later as a derived table. A VARCHAR(..) is a single value and cannot be used with `in` later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
declare @codeList VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')  FROM  @codes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item));
```

Your `select` returns two results (120, 110), but a scalar `VARCHAR` variable can only hold one.

You can fix it by creating a table variable:

```
DECLARE @codeList TABLE (code varchar(100));
INSERT @codeList 
SELECT  
  T.Item.value('@Value[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')  
FROM  @codes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item);
```

And then change `(@codes IS NULL OR DataCode IN ( @codeList))` to `(@codes IS NULL OR DataCode IN (SELECT code FROM @codeList))`

Here, a `LEFT JOIN` should perform better than your current syntax, e.g.

```
WITH CODE_RESULT AS(      
  SELECT  ID, Name, Region,
  FROM dbo.MyTable1  t1 
  LEFT JOIN @codeList  cl
  ON t1.DataCode = cl.code
```

You may have to add additional logic to check if `cl.code` `is null` depending on your intentions.

Comment: Okay, how can I fix the issue? How to store both the values (there could be many in future) in a variable and reuse in the select statement's?

Comment: Edited to explain further.  I wasn't sure initially if you wanted to keep the varchar or not.

Comment: There's a "INTO" missing after your INSERT +1 from me

Comment: INTO is not required in T-SQL - and if you're worried about portability, other DBMS will have different syntax for creating a table variable, if they even support them.

Comment: tried this solution and it works but, I see a performance issue when I go with "(@codes IS NULL OR DataCode IN (SELECT code FROM @codeList))". For example: Let's say I have one value in parameter, the current sql works as is now and takes 2 seconds to bring the data. But, with this new solution for the same single parameter, it takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Updated.  A join should perform a little better, but you're still going to have differences in performance.  Check the query plan - a temp table might help things but probably not since you're only dealing with a single column.  You could also try doing a `SELECT DISTINCT` in your `INSERT` t omake sure you're not getting duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to store multiple values for use later, use a TABLE VARIABLE to hold the results, like this:

```
DECLARE @dataCodes TABLE (DataCode varchar(MAX));
INSERT INTO @dataCodes
    SELECT T.Item.value('@Value[1]', 'varchar(max)')
      FROM @codes.nodes('/Root/List') AS T(Item);
```

You can then use the "`WHERE DataCode IN (SELECT DataCode FROM @dataCodes)`" to do the select and get all the results.

Comment: I tried your solution (in fact, everyone answered here suggested almost the same)... it works but, I see a performance issue when I go with "WHERE DataCode IN (SELECT DataCode FROM @dataCodes)". For example: Let's say I have one value in parameter, the sql works as is now and takes 2 seconds to bring the data. But, with this new solution for the same single parameter, it takes 15 seconds.

Comment: You may want to look at the Query Plan, and see if there are any obvious indexes you could add.  Note that Table Variables perform well when they're used to store a SMALL amount of data (like, fewer than ten rows).  If you're expecting more, it's better to use a TEMP Table (which has valid statistics for better query plans). You can also index TEMP tables more easily (Table Variables can only have an optional Primary Key).

Answer (score 3):

You create a table variable

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/474ff/6)**

```
Declare @T_variable table(name varchar(200));

insert into @T_variable 
SELECT ID FROM Table1;

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
   (SELECT *
    FROM @T_variable)
;

GO
```